# the relation is not appending to the model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to append a relation to my model in laravel i know its possible with resource but i need it to be appened to model so here its like below what i do :

```
 protected $appends = ['accommodation_rooms'];
    public function getAccommodationRoomsAttribute(){
        return $this->accommodationRooms();
    }
```

and my relation is :

```
 public function accommodationRooms()
    {
        return $this->Hasmany(AccommodationRoom::class);
    }
```

but when i run my api it returns null but when i call the relation it has the relation and it has no problem . any idea what i am doing wrong ??

## EDIT

```
  $data = Accommodation::with('city', 'accommodationFacilities', 'gallery')
            ->where('is_deleted', 0)->Paginate(env('PAGINATE_NUMBER'));
        return $data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return $this->accommodationRooms()` will return an instance of query builder. That is probably why it was showing empty.

Change it to

```
public function getAccommodationRoomsAttribute(){
    return $this->accommodationRooms;
}
```

Comment: message: "Undefined property: App\Accommodation::$accommodationRooms",

Comment: Can you update the answer with the code of how you are querying the model?

Comment: I am not quering that i am appending to model

Comment: I understand. But you are returning this model from a controller somewhere?

Comment: Why did you accept it? What have you changed? I also wonder, why don't you eager load the relation like you did with the gallery?

Comment: it worked idk how and why :) i want to append the cheapest room to hotel so i always have it without any further logic and ram usage

Answer (score 1):

Call it without `()`

```
public function getAccommodationRoomsAttribute(){
    return $this->accommodation_rooms;
}
```

And update your relation to:

```
 public function accommodationRooms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AccommodationRoom::class);
    }
```

And make sure you have `accommodation_id` column in your `accommodation_rooms` table

Comment: still i get null i am sure it has relation